# show the file timestamp and select latest file from the directory using Scala in azure databricks

Tags: scala, azure-databricks

I want to select the latest file from the directory and show the timestamp of all the files using scala code in azure databricks .

Can you please help me on this .

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this using below code , which is working fine .

```
`var basePath = "<Full_Path>"

 var files = Array[String]()
 var maxTS: Long = 0
 var TimeFile = collection.mutable.Map[Long, String]()
 val conf = new Configuration()
 val hdfs = FileSystem.get( conf )

 val f = new Path( basePath )
 val messageFile = hdfs.listFiles( f, true )

 while (messageFile.hasNext()) {
    val message = messageFile.next()
    if (message.getPath.toString().endsWith( "tsv" )) {
        files = files :+ message.getPath.toString()          
        TimeFile += ( message.getModificationTime -> message.getPath.toString())        

    }
  }`
```